# how to select radio button & checkbox in selenium webdriver with java?

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox, webdriver, radio-button

how to select radio button & checkbox in selenium webdriver with java?

Answer (score 1):

**For selecting Radio button**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ValidRadio_3']")).click();
```

**For selecting Checkbox**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ValidCheckbox_1']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer** : select radio button & checkbox in selenium webdriver with java go through below code.

**Click on Radio button :**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("RadioBtn_ID")).click();
```

**Click on Checkbox :**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Checkbox_ID")).click();
```

For more details with brief description go through below link.

http://stqatools.com/selenium-checkbox-radio-button/